# save Performance Monitor settings

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring

I have added several counters to Window 2008 Performance Monitor to monitor web application. When I restart server or close Server Manager console I loose all added monitor. I do not see a way to save and later load counters and every time adding the same counters are boring and takes some time. How to save counters?

Answer (score 0):

from the file menu... File... Save As...

Comment: There is no Save As.

Comment: To be clear, you're running perfmon.msc, right? If not, then run it, add your counters, and save as

Comment: Yes and File option has only Options and Exit menu. I use Windows 2008 R2. There is no Save As.

Comment: OK. Your question and your tag both state Windows Server 2008, not Windows Server 2008 R2. You might want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own DCS (Data Collector Set), add counters you need, configure schedule, duration, stop conditions and other options.

[Create a Data Collector Set Manually](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766404.aspx)

To view logged data at a later time, right-click on plot and select Properties > Source Tab > Log files (specify log file created already).
Then add counters you want to view.